# Apache Camel Keystore Jetty Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, apache-camel, jetty, keystore

I'm building an application for my work and came across an issue I don't know quite how to solve. We're creating a Camel Jetty Proxy that is supposed to connect to an HTTPS website. We got the proxy up for non-secure sites easily, but now we're running into issues with connecting to a secure website with Camel and Jetty.

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: JettyClient failed cause by: General SSLEngine problem. Exchange[ID-jasonm-win7-53769-1497563726897-0-1]. Caused by: [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - General SSLEngine problem]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9.doTaskCompleted(JettyContentExchange9.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9.onConnectionFailed(JettyContentExchange9.java:130)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9$1.onFailure(JettyContentExchange9.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.RequestNotifier.notifyFailure(RequestNotifier.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.RequestNotifier.notifyFailure(RequestNotifier.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abort(HttpSender.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.anyToFailure(HttpSender.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender$CommitCallback.failed(HttpSender.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP$HeadersCallback.failed(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher$PendingState.fail(WriteFlusher.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.onFail(WriteFlusher.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.close(AbstractEndPoint.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.close(SslConnection.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1364)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:807)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:775)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:525)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1708)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:303)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:865)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:862)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1302)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:630)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1356)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 29 more
```

Upon review we found out that it's because we weren't accepting the certificate. So we found this code online that takes in the *.jks files and will allow for a secure connection

```
private void configureSslForJetty()
{
    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource("c:\\Projects\\blah\\fakefilter.jks");
    ksp.setPassword("123456");

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    kmp.setKeyPassword("export-password");

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

    JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
    jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
}

private void configureSslForHttp4()
{
    KeyStoreParameters trust_ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    trust_ksp.setResource("c:\\Projects\\blah\\fakeca.jks");
    trust_ksp.setPassword("123456");

    TrustManagersParameters trustp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    trustp.setKeyStore(trust_ksp);

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setTrustManagers(trustp);

    HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
    httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
}
```

The problem that we're not understanding is that I don't know where the *.jks file is coming from OR where the passwords are coming from. Where does this information reside? Is there a relative path that I can follow to get the *.jks files?

Comment: Google a bit more about Java SSL and certificates. JKS is Java Key Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running javas keytool, you can insert the certificate into Java's Keystore which will solve the issue of not finding the certificates. There was no need for the Keystore code.

https://support2.microfocus.com/techdocs/2680.html